# Need to show the value of the product in the value attribute of input element but it is not giving any value. Where is this get product function?

Tags: module, custom, modal-popup

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $buttonTitl = __('Get Quote'); ?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitl) ?>"
                    class="action primary" 
                     disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitl) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="click-me">Get Quote</a>
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <form class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
          <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
           <div class="field required">
               <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="field required">
               <label for="product_name" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Product Name') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" 
                    id="product_name" value="" title="<?php echo __('Product Name') ?>" class="input-text" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            title: 'Get Quote',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
        $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
            $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
        });

    }
    );
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to get??

Comment: this is giving blank not giving value and I need the product name to be printed in my modal form

Comment: find below my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$block->getProduct();

above function is loading from below file

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\View.php
```

You can use `value="<?= $_product->getName(); ?>"`

hope this helps you :)

Comment: when I am placing its value in the value attribute of product name input then its not showing anything

Comment: could you please tell me what this $_product  returns?

Comment: Thank you so much. You are really a great contributor in this community.

Comment: Happy to here this words..and this works for you..$_product return all attributes of product. You can print array or log array for get all attributes value.

Answer (score 0):

as you already have loaded the product :

> $_product = $block->getProduct();

you can use $_product to get all the product attributes

e.g:

```
$_product->getName();
$_product->getSku();
$_product->getQty();
```

try to use **echo $_product->getName();** in input value